# Firebase unable to initialize

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

so I am trying to create a sign up page on Flutter, I wrote the code attached below for the main.dart file and somehow I still get the error like this when I click the sign up button:

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Here is the code in the main.dart page:

```
import 'package:deli_app/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:deli_app/screens/signin_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // TRY THIS: Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see
        // the application has a purple toolbar. Then, without quitting the app,
        // try changing the seedColor in the colorScheme below to Colors.green
        // and then invoke "hot reload" (save your changes or press the "hot
        // reload" button in a Flutter-supported IDE, or press "r" if you used
        // the command line to start the app).
        //
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // state is not lost during the reload. To reset the state, use hot
        // restart instead.
        //
        // This works for code too, not just values: Most code changes can be
        // tested with just a hot reload.
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const SignInScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

I have put the firebase initialization codes and somehow the error is still there, the submitted information weren't stored in the firebase too.

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added the **firebase_core** package to project pubspec.yaml file.